# Google research console ''Page is not mobile friendly''

Tags: google, research

I have recently created portfolio website for myself, using WordPress. However after adding it to google console. It says that my website isn't mobile friendly. However, clearly when you go to the website on a mobile device, it works perfectly.  I'm a beginner in terms of web dev. I hope there is an east fix.

Thank you all for your help.

Website: Danielgola.com

GSC screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Clickable elements too close together" means that your hyperlinks are too close to each other. It's probably looking at the vertical space between your images as well as your horizontal spacing in your menu.

Have you tried viewing your page using your browser's developer tools and enabling Responsive Design?  This can be a helpful tool for viewing your content in different mobile layouts.